# Plot a ball rolling down a curve

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I want to "animate" a circle rolling over the sin graph, I made a code where the circle moves rapidly down a straight line, now I want the same but the acceleration will be changing.

My previous code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

theta = np.arange(0, np.pi * 2, (0.01 * np.pi))
x = np.arange(-50, 1, 1)
y = x - 7
plt.figure()
for t in np.arange(0, 4, 0.1):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    xc = ((-9.81 * t**2 * np.sin(np.pi / 2)) / 3) + (5 * np.cos(theta))
    yc = ((-9.81 * t**2 * np.sin(np.pi / 2)) / 3) + (5 * np.sin(theta))
    plt.plot(xc, yc, 'r')
    xp = ((-9.81 * t**2 * np.sin(np.pi / 2)) / 3) + (5 * np.cos(np.pi * t))
    yp = ((-9.81 * t**2 * np.sin(np.pi / 2)) / 3) + (5 * np.sin(np.pi * t))
    plt.plot(xp, yp, 'bo')
    plt.pause(0.01)
    plt.cla()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by numerically integrating:

```
 dt = 0.01
 lst_x = []
 lst_y = []
 t = 0
 while t < 10: #for instance
      t += dt
      a = get_acceleration(function, x)
      x += v * dt + 0.5 * a * dt * dt
      v += a * dt
      y = get_position(fuction, x)
      lst_x.append(x)
      lst_y.append(y)
```

**This is assuming the ball never leaves your slope! If it does, you'll also have to integrate in y in a similar way as done in x!!**

Where your acceleration is going to be equal to `g * cos(slope)`.